# Can I change byte in memory offset of exe app when launching it from java app?

Tags: java, memory, offset

**Greetings!**
*First of all, I'm aware of that this can be easily made with C++ (via dll inject), but I really need to know if this action can be made with Java.*

Is it possible to change memory offset data of an .exe (C/++ coded) application that launches from Java code?

**For example:**
Need to start exe app via Java through

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\PathToExeFile\\MyApp.exe").start();
```

Before/Then I need to change byte in memory offset, let it be **0x01a7da** offset, that contain **0x1A** byte, which needs to be changed to **0xFF**, or even sequence of bytes 0x1A004B to 0xFFFFFF.

Comment: A byte in the file MyApp.exe still would be feasible. You could start that virus code in C++ in java, that will start the exe.

Comment: Can you provide more details? If I understand you correctly, you are saying that I need to use native c++ code in java to start that exe with memory editing?

Comment: Make a C++ app that launches MyApp and patches the memory, and launch that in ProcessBuilder.

Comment: That would make no sense to use Java, tho I need only Java app + MyApp.exe, otherwise I could just make c++ dll with memory hooks and inject it in MyApp.exe, unfortunatelly, forced to use Java method.

Comment: With java JNI you may access a DLL but you are right: java itself does not provide such very low-level system access.